# Read Word 2007 file and extract text, comments, and commenter name using ASP.NET/C#

Tags: asp.net, ms-word, comments, extract, word-2007

I have an ASP.NET app that permits Word 2007 document uploads. Once they are uploaded I'd like to parse out the document text and also any comments made by reviewers. I'd like to be able to get the comments and the commenter initials/name.

Are there free libaries to do this? I prefer not to automate Word as this process needs to be somewhat scalable..

Answer (score 1):

DocX (check codeplex) might do what you need. I know you are looking for free, but if you find that you need more features (97-2003 support, for example) than you can find in free offerings, take a look at Aspose's products. I rely on their .NET suite for a number of commercial apps and have been, overall, very happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you require that your users upload Word 2007 DOCX files (as opposed to Word 2003 .doc files), you can use the `System.IO.Packaging` API in WindowsBase.dll to read the XML within the Word 2007 file (See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266220.aspx))